# building app to Device; want to kill process and then be able to restart it so that I can see NSLog messages in Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I am trying to debug an issue in an app which only seems to happen when restarted on the phone after a build. What I'd like to be able to do is connect device via usb, build app to device, kill the process on the device, and then restart app on device so that NSLog messages are transmitted to Xcode. Is this possible?

thx in advance if anyone knows how to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open the organizer (cmd+shift+2 by default) and go to the devices tab, you should be able to view the console of any connected device by selecting "Console" under that device

Comment: Also we can use tools such as iPhone Congiguration Utility to look at this logs.